# SQL: Convert varchar to date

Tags: sql, oracle, date, type-conversion, varchar

I have the following varchar type variable that I need to convert to date:

```
2019-07-24T13:52:04
```

When I do the following select:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(createddt,'YYYY-MM-DD T HH:MM:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD T HH:MM:SS')
FROM tbl$orders;
```

it gives me an error message:

> date format not recognized.

How to convert this varchar to date?

Comment: change `'YYYY-MM-DD T HH:MM:SS'` to `'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS'`. Why convert to date and than back to char with the same format?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to speculate that you are using Oracle because it has `to_date()` and in Oracle, the `date` data type has a time component.

This then works:

```
select to_date('2019-07-24T13:52:04', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
from dual;
```

Comment: There is no T in your output.

Comment: @user11913918 . . . I have no idea what you are referring to.  This is converting the specified string to a date.

Comment: ibb.co/8myjBvf See, there is no letter T in your output.

Comment: *"There is no T in your output."* That's because `"T"` is not part of the standard Oracle date format. The output from the query will be in the Oracle date format, so if you want a T you gotta ask for it: `alter session set nls_date_format =  'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS';`

Answer (score 0):

Is that what are you looking for

```
SELECT TO_DATE(REPLACE('2019-07-24T13:52:04', 'T', ' '), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
FROM Dual;
```

Comment: There is no T in your output.

Comment: @user11913918 You say _"Convert varchar to date"_ that's [ISO 8601](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) it's already ISO 8601 format.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Date format in Oracle is defined by `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` and you need to set it according to your requirement.

You are not able to see the letter T as your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is not set like that way.

You can try the following example for your problem:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS'; -- setting the date format to be displayed at the session level

SELECT
    TO_DATE('2019-07-24T13:52:04', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')
FROM
    DUAL; -- Your query
```

Also, Please read about `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` from oracle documentation. It is really needed to understand how dates are stored and how it is displayed in oracle.

Cheers!!